# High Relative absolute error and Root relative squared error in classification

Tags: classification, weka

I have a small problem with my model
[JRip classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aomim.jpg)

The output seems to be good enough but I'm worrying about the high Relative absolute error and Root relative squared error. When I tried J48 and NaiveBayes it was about 98% so high as well. Is it not so important in the classification and I can just leave like this? Otherwise, how can I improve it?
The cost matrix is:

0 1

2 0

what improved the result for the TP Rate for second class.
Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relative absolute error (and analogically Root relative squared error) is calculated as the Mean absolute error divided by the error of the `ZeroR classifier` (a classifier, that ignores all predictors and simply selects the most frequent value - **a** in your case). You can check the formula [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/mooc/dataminingwithweka/slides/Class4-DataMiningWithWeka-2013.pdf).
 
If you look a the **Confusion Matrix**, you see that you have `719 a cases` and `303 b cases`. The ZeroR classifier would classify all cases as **a**, getting **70% of the training data set correctly**. To compare, your model is getting 66% correctly (!).
The value of the Relative absolute error is not very important in your case (classification), since the value of error as such does not really matter (you look for **either 1 or 2**, not caring if the prediction model calculates 1.88 or 1.77 **as long as it selects the correct class**). However, as noted, your model does not score very well and the value over 100% is an idication of it.
As for model improvements, it's hard to say withouth knowing more information. But you could try differen algorythms, like KNN for instance. A good explanation with an example could be found [on the IBM developerworks Blog](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka3/index.html)